# fetching the current date in sql

Tags: php, sql, mysql

in the databse i have the format of the date like 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

how can i fetch the current date in this format? and then if i want to calculate the date after 1 week how can i do that.

thanxx in advance. 
Using php and mysql.

Comment: Reference: mySQL Date and time functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html - `NOW()` and `DATE_ADD()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use MySQL to fetch the date if you just want to know the current date in PHP. You can use PHP's [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
```

If you want the date one week from now, use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/strtotime):

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week'));
```

Comment: It is always worth remembering that often the date & time on the MySQL server can be different to that of the web server, especially with shared hosting where it isn't setup problem, so only using the date from the MySQL server and using this with the PHP functions will prevent problems related to differing times.

Answer (score 4):

Try [CURDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate):

```
> SELECT CURDATE();
-> '2010-10-07'
```

To add 7 days use an interval:

```
> SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK;
-> '2010-10-14'
```

Answer (score 1):

ref: [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual :: 11 Functions and Operators :: 11.7 Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) using the [formats defined](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) in DATE_FORMAT

```
select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') as date;
```

or

```
select DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK,'%Y-%m-%d') as date
```

where the INTERVAL is one of the following: [mysql interval formats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)